# Controlling where the cursor will end up

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write a macro that will leave cursor in the middle of the two senteneces. But so far i have failed to do so. Either nothing is happening or SendInput is displayed on the screen.

What i want it to look like;

Greetings,

*Cursor here*

With regards.

What i have tried so far,

```
::/gre::
(
Greetings,



With regards.
)
SendInput {Up 3}
return
```

or

```
::/gre::
(
Greetings,



With regards.
)
SendInput {Up 3}
return
```

I couldn't find any examples on combining these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text)

```
::/gre::
Send {text}
(
Greetings,



With regards.
)
SendInput {Up 3}
return
```